# Android studio updated and code too large now

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a system that has been produced for 2 years now. It is an EMM system for controlling corporate devices.

It uses `FireBase` to send the functionality executed on the device from the server app to the device.

There are around 400 possible commands you can send to a device and all these commands are handled in one class initially, which overrides the `onMessageReceived()` from the `FireBaseMessagingService` class.

The older version of Android studio built the apk which is now in production. I have started to work on version 2 of my system after about a year off. so I updated my Android studio to the latest (4).

The Problem:

when I try to build the project and push onto a device, I get

```
error: code too large public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
```

As stated before this `onMessageReceived` method can handle 400 different types of push notifications from the server app, so there are a lot of if/else statements in the method body.

Is there any reason why since the AS upgrade this will not work?

is there any setting I can change in AS to get past this?

What I have tried:

I thought about putting half of the if/else in another service class, to cut down on the method code. This would involve passing the `remoteMessageMap` to another class to carry on with the if/else processing.

`remoteMessageMap` from FireBase is a Map and Maps are not serializable as they extend the interface, so can't pass it.

```
public class MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyAndroidFCMService";
    AppObj appObj;


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        Log.e(TAG, "remoteMessage.getData() = " + remoteMessage.getData());

        Map remoteMessageMap = remoteMessage.getData();

        String message = (String)remoteMessageMap.get("message");
```

thanks

[edit1]

```
else if(message.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("CLEARCACHE_REMOVE_APP_WL")){


            Log.e(TAG, "received CLEARCACHE_REMOVE_APP_WL");

            String pushGuid =  (String)remoteMessageMap.get("pushguid");
            Log.e(TAG, "pushGuid = " + pushGuid);

            String clearCacheRemoveWhitelist =  (String)remoteMessageMap.get("clear_cache_app_names");


            Intent intentExecutePushCommand = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), ExecutePushCommandIntentService.class);
            intentExecutePushCommand.putExtra("compID", MenuActivity.companyID);
            intentExecutePushCommand.putExtra("command", message);
            intentExecutePushCommand.putExtra("pushguid", pushGuid);
            intentExecutePushCommand.putExtra("clear_cache_app_names", clearCacheRemoveWhitelist);



            startService(intentExecutePushCommand);

        }else if(message.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("CLEARCACHE_GET_PACKAGENAMES_WL")){


            Log.e(TAG, "received CLEARCACHE_GET_PACKAGENAMES_WL");

            String pushGuid =  (String)remoteMessageMap.get("pushguid");
            Log.e(TAG, "pushGuid = " + pushGuid);


            Intent intentExecutePushCommand = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), ExecutePushCommandIntentService.class);
            intentExecutePushCommand.putExtra("compID", MenuActivity.companyID);
            intentExecutePushCommand.putExtra("command", message);
            intentExecutePushCommand.putExtra("pushguid", pushGuid);

            startService(intentExecutePushCommand);

        }else if(message.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("CLEARCACHE_ADD_PACKAGENAME_WL")){


            Log.e(TAG, "received CLEARCACHE_ADD_PACKAGENAME_WL");

            String pushGuid =  (String)remoteMessageMap.get("pushguid");
            Log.e(TAG, "pushGuid = " + pushGuid);

            String packageName =  (String)remoteMessageMap.get("package_name");


            Intent intentExecutePushCommand = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), ExecutePushCommandIntentService.class);
            intentExecutePushCommand.putExtra("compID", MenuActivity.companyID);
            intentExecutePushCommand.putExtra("command", message);
            intentExecutePushCommand.putExtra("pushguid", pushGuid);
            intentExecutePushCommand.putExtra("package_name", packageName);

            startService(intentExecutePushCommand);

        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to pass the `remoteMessageMap` to another class. The source of the problem is the limitation in the java method size. Here is a piece of the [official documentation of oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.3) which is related to this problem:

> code_length
> The value of the code_length item gives the number of bytes in the code array for this method.
> The value of code_length must be greater than zero (as the code array must not be empty) and less than 65536.

The point is that your `onMessageReceived` method is too long, which is bigger than 64KB of compiled code. It is weird why it was compiled fine in previous versions of Android Studio :)

Anyway, the solution is to break the method into smaller fragments. My suggestion is fragmentation by some message types. For example:

```java
private static final String COMMAND_1 = "COMMAND_1";
private static final String COMMAND_2 = "COMMAND_2";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "remoteMessage.getData() = " + remoteMessage.getData());

    Map remoteMessageMap = remoteMessage.getData();

    String message = (String) remoteMessageMap.get("message");
    
    String type = extrated_from_received_message;

    switch (type) {
        case COMMAND_1:
            handleCommand1(remoteMessageMap);
            break;
        case COMMAND_2:
            handleCommand2(remoteMessageMap);
            break;

        // more commands ...

        default:
            // ...
    }
}

private void handleCommand1(Map remoteMessageMap){
    // do whatever related to command 1
}

private void handleCommand2(Map remoteMessageMap){
    // do whatever related to command 2
}
```

In this way, the method size would be optimized and the performance of calling it will be far improved.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. ok well the message from the push notification is the key. The system can receive around 400 different types of push notification. These push notifications have a key and sometimes additional parameters. i could do the switch on the message. For example all functionality that interacts with the cache on the phone for an app with start with CLEARCACHE so icould intercept the notification, extract the message and check if it starts with CLEARCACHE. if yes, then fire a second method that handles only CLEARCACHE stuff. Example in edit 1

Comment: edit 1 is the original code, so i could take all the if /else that are to do with clearcache and put them in a second method. Then in the orginal code check for if message starts with "CLEARCACHE" -. then second method?

Comment: You're welcome dude :) Yeah, it could be a good idea to handle the branches of operations, in two levels, as you said. So, you can put all the lines of code which are in common, into a `handleClearCache` method, then call another method which is related to a specific CLEARCACHE command. So in this case, you can create the intent and put `compID`, `command`, and `pushguid` extras in the `handleClearCache` method (in common operations), and pass this intent plus `remoteMessageMap` to the second level methods to put further extras (if needed) and call the `startService`.

Comment: create a method for common code like below and call it with parameters
 Intent intentExecutePushCommand = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), ExecutePushCommandIntentService.class);
            intentExecutePushCommand.putExtra("compID", MenuActivity.companyID);
            intentExecutePushCommand.putExtra("command", message);
            intentExecutePushCommand.putExtra("pushguid", pushGuid);

            startService(intentExecutePushCommand);

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are repeating the same lines of code a lot of times, just put these lines of code and maybe a few more in a separate method that is called on each `else if` and this will reduce the size of `onMessageReceived()`

```
   Intent intentExecutePushCommand = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), ExecutePushCommandIntentService.class);
   intentExecutePushCommand.putExtra("compID", MenuActivity.companyID);
   intentExecutePushCommand.putExtra("command", message);
   intentExecutePushCommand.putExtra("pushguid", pushGuid);
```